# How many independent power settings does the Yaesu FT-897/857 have?

Tags: yaesu, equipment-operation

I have found, and the manual agrees, that the Yaesu FT-897 (and presumably the essentially identical FT-857) stores multiple “RF POWER SET” values, for different bands.

The manual simply describes this value as “for the current band”, but I have found that not every band has a separate value. Which bands have separate power values?

I would like this information so that I can know when I need to change the setting if I am changing bands but want to use the same power, or so that if I have been using high power and want to reset everything to low power to avoid damage to sensitive equipment, I can be sure I have reset it for all bands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empirically, there are four independent power settings.

```
HF          0-32.99999 MHz     5-100 W
50 MHz     33-56               5-100
VHF        76-164              5-50
UHF       420-470              2-20
```

The frequency ranges shown exceed those in which the FT-897 will transmit, of course, but it will still display a particular one of the four stored values for any given tunable frequency.